# Dropdown should open on single click in datagrid winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, combobox

I have set the **EditMode** property to **EditorEnter** then to on single click i cant access the dropdown.

On gridcellclick is wrote the code

```
 If (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
{
SendKeys.SendWait("{F4}")
}
```

and also is wrote the code

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

But the result was same. I was not able to access the dropdown on single click. It takes 2 click to open dropdown.

UPDATE:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
                ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
     if (combo != null)
                {
                    combo.Enter -= new EventHandler(combo_Enter);
                    combo.Enter += new EventHandler(combo_Enter);
                }
         }
```

Comment: What is `comboBox1`? How is it relates to `DataGrid`?

Comment: comboBox1 is dynamically binded to DataGrid column number 5

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the line `comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`, it stops there?

Comment: see my updated question. this is how i call the comboBox1_Enter event and yes it stops on breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox != null)
    {
        comboBox.Enter -= comboBox_Enter;
        comboBox.Enter += comboBox_Enter;
    }
}

private void comboBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;
}
```